# Find the K Largest SubString

Tags: arrays, string, algorithm, sorting

I am giving a String `S` of length `10^5` , Now for all possible `N+1C2` substring i have to  output the `K` substring when all substring are sorted in ascending order.

```
For Ex:
S= STACK

Substring:
  A
  AC
  ACK
  C
  CK
  S
  ST
  STA ... so on
```

`My Approach` :  Generate All the Substring sort them and output the `K` Substring

Then i came to know about `Suffix` Array , for a given string i have generated the suffix array , but how to compute the `K` element using suffix array ?
Can you please explain how to use `Suffix Array` to compute the `K` element ?

I have generated and Understand the suffix array ? But how to use it.
[Suffix Array Algorithm Used](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/suffix-array-set-2-a-nlognlogn-algorithm/)

Answer (score -1):

The suffix tree gives you all the suffixes of the string. So if the string is "stack" the longest suffix is stack$ (we add a dummy extra character to prevent any suffix being a prefix of another suffix). The next longest is tack$, then ack$. All these are accessible from the root.

Now a sub-string is just a prefix to a suffix. By walking the tree, you get all the sub-strings, sorted. That's one, rather expensive solution.
To make the search cheaper, say we want K = 5. We have a suffix begins A and it has three paths to the end symbol, $. So A is not the start of our suffix, We have no suffix begins B, so that's not our answer. WE have a suffix begins C, and it has two paths to $. So for k = 5, the first letter of the suffix must be 'C'. We then extend. We lost three positions to a, so we need the second suffix under the first C node.